# Merge function failed to conduct on GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, merge

I want to merge two `ImageCollection` on GEE simply with `merge()` function . According to the document on GEE website (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-merge), I only need to use the `merge()` function. However, my result returned

> Line 287: res2L2017c1_6_Veg.merge is not a function

This is my GEE code. https://code.earthengine.google.com/c0bc5edacd177b0acaf0330670f759c7

I have no clue why it is not working, is it due to the `reduceRegion` part on line 138 and line 235 (for sentinel2 and sentinel1 individually)? Because the output of the `reduceRegion` is the input to `merge()`.

Update:
I have also tried to merge the `ImageCollection` that was produced before doing the `reduceRegion`, and it still filed to merge.

```js
var merge_s1s2 = s2L2017c1_6_Veg.merge(s1L20171_6_predb);
print(merge_s1s2) //this is merging two imagecollection from line 121 and line 228

var merge_res1s2 = res2L2017c1_6_Veg.merge(res1L20171_6_predb);
print(merge_res1s2) //this is merging two imagecollection from line 138 and line 235
```

Comment: The output of `.reduceRegion` is a dictionary (see https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reduceregion), not an ImageCollection -- so you cannot use `.merge()` on it. This applies to `res2L2017c1_6_Veg`. For `s1L20171_6_predb`, you used `.median()` which gives you an `ee.Image`, not an `ee.ImageCollection`, so again - you cannot use `.merge()`.

Comment: @OliverLopez thank you for your comment. I also realize that they are `ee.image` instead of `ee.imagecollection`, so the `.merge()` cannot be done. However, do you know any other ways that I can combine the S2 and S1 data together, making the dataset contains all the bands from S1 and S2?

Answer (score 0):

I simply solved the problem using `addBands()` function since it is an `image` instead of an `imageCollection`.

````
var S1_2017_VV = s1L20171_6_predb.select('VV');
var S1_2017_VH = s1L20171_6_predb.select('VH');

var S1S2 = s2L2017c1_6_Veg.addBands(S1_2017_VV).addBands(S1_2017_VH);
print(S1S2);```
````